# Switch if-statement for something different

Tags: c

I'm trying to switch if-statement. I'm trying to load a file called file.txt.
File looks like this

[image: file.txt]

My code:

```
typedef struct info {
    char        name[99];
    char        age[99];
    char        sex[99];
    struct      node *next;
}info_t;

void load(info_t **head){
    FILE *file;
    char buffer[255];
    int counter = 0;
    int number_entries = 0;
    info_t *help = NULL;
    info_t *current = NULL;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(buffer, 255, file)){
       if (counter == 0){
            help = (info_t*)malloc(sizeof(info_t));
       }
       if (counter == 0){
            printf(strcpy(help->name, buffer));
       }
       if (counter == 1){
            printf(strcpy(help->age, buffer));
       }
       if (counter == 2){
            printf(strcpy(help->sex, buffer));
       }
       counter++;
    }
}
```

I tried switch, but it`s not really working. Any ideas?

Comment: Put the file in the question as text, not as a picture.

Comment: switch will only execute one case, assuming that you put breaks in everycase. Seems like to me that if-else will work fine for you.

Comment: where did you try `switch`? `switch(counter){ case 0: case 1: etc` should work if you want to do it that way. In either case, combine all the `if (counter==0)` work into one body, no sense in checking it twice for what you've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try something more like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct info {
    char        name[99];
    char        age[99];
    char        sex[99];
    struct info *next;
} info_t;

void load(info_t **head)
{
    char buffer[255];
    int counter = 0;
    info_t *inrec = NULL;
    info_t *current = NULL;
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Couldn't open input 'file.txt'\n");
        return;
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file))
    {
        // remove trailing newline
        int i = strlen(buffer) - 1;
        while( buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
        }

        switch(counter) {
        case 0: //line with ***
            inrec = (info_t*)malloc(sizeof(info_t));
            if(!inrec) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERR: Couldn't allocate memory.\n");
                return;
            }
            break;

        case 1: //line with name
            strncpy(inrec->name, buffer, sizeof(inrec->name));
            inrec->name[sizeof(inrec->name)-1] = '\0'; // ensure termination
            break;

        case 2: //line with age
            strncpy(inrec->age, buffer, sizeof(inrec->age));
            inrec->age[sizeof(inrec->age)-1] = '\0'; // ensure termination
            break;

        case 3: //line with sex
            strncpy(inrec->sex, buffer, sizeof(inrec->sex));
            inrec->sex[sizeof(inrec->sex)-1] = '\0'; // ensure termination
            inrec->next = NULL;

            // insert into list
            if(*head == NULL) { // first node
                *head = inrec;
                current = inrec; //current points to last node inserted
            }
            else if(current) {
                current->next = inrec;
                current = inrec; //current points to last node inserted
            }

            // reset to prepare for next record
            inrec = NULL;
            counter = -1;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    if(counter != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: A partial record at the end of the file wasn't completely read.\n");
        free(inrec); // don't leak memory
    }
}

int main(void)
{
   info_t *root = NULL;
   info_t *p;

   load(&root);
   for(p = root; p; p = p->next)
       printf("name: '%s'\tage: '%s'\tsex: '%s'\n", p->name, p->age, p->sex);

   return 0;
}
```